# How can you get the order back after using argsort?

Tags: python, numpy

So I have an array for example `[-0.7, -3.7, -2.1, -5.8, -1.2 ]`
and these particular numbers correspond to labels which are in order: say 0.7 corresponds to label 201, 3.7 to label 202 and so on.

On sorting them normally, I receive [-5.8, -3.7, -2.1, -1.2, -0.7]. I am interested in picking out the top 3 values out of these but on sorting, I would lose track of the labels.
Now to sort them in order I use *np.argsort*. This gives me `[1,2,0]`. This tells me the value with 4 has a low probability while the one with 0 has a high probability.

My question is with argsort, how can I get my mappings back? How can I tell where my labels are now? Is there a way I can keep a track of them while using argsort?

Comment: why not just make a copy?

Comment: "This changes my array to say  `[12, 23,34,56,11]`." - how the hell? Show us some example code. What you're describing doesn't make sense.

Comment: @wim: make a copy of? This is just an example, what I am working with is huge array with about 90 values inside, so then it gets trickier.

Comment: why not make an object with both label and the value you use in the example array, than sort them by the value and it'll keep their labels attached. also, 90 values are not enough to be considered non efficient to keep a copy of, especially if they're simple values.

Comment: @CoderQueen: 60 Million entries is something you should mention, quite obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes a copy and uses the built-in sorted method, but I think it achieves what you want.

```
vals = [-0.7, -3.7, -2.1, -5.8, -1.2 ]
label_inds_vals = sorted([thing for thing in enumerate(vals)], key=lambda x: x[1])
```

The sorted values also come with indices that you can use to index their corresponding label in the label array.

If list of lists:

value_lists = [[-0.7, -3.2, -2.1, -5.8, -1.2], [-1.2, -3.2, -3.4, -5.4, -6.4]]

```
for vals in value_lists:
    #reverse depending if you want top 3 or bottom
    label_inds_vals = sorted([thing for thing in enumerate(vals)], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)         
    print label_inds_vals[:3]
```

Comment: Just a question, what if my *vals* looks like this: 
[[-0.7, -3.2, -2.1, -5.8, -1.2], 
[-1.2, -3.2, -3.4, -5.4, -6.4]] 
like a list of lists and I want to sort them and print the top 3 of each list. How would the label_inds_vals change?

Comment: you could iterate over your list of lists, and do the procedure for each inner list

Answer (score 4):

It's a little unclear what you mean by 'where my labels are now`.

But maybe this use of `argsort` will help

```
In [163]: values=np.array([-0.7, -3.7, -2.1, -5.8, -1.2 ])
```

make an array of the labels as well:

```
In [164]: labels=np.array([200,201,202,203,204])
```

`argsort` gives an array of indices, which can be used to reorder both `values` and `labels`. Note that this application does not change the original arrays.

```
In [165]: ind=np.argsort(values)
In [166]: ind
Out[166]: array([3, 1, 2, 4, 0], dtype=int32)
In [167]: values[ind]
Out[167]: array([-5.8, -3.7, -2.1, -1.2, -0.7])
In [168]: labels[ind]
Out[168]: array([203, 201, 202, 204, 200])
```

If I apply `argsort` to `ind` I get another set of indices that lets me resort values back to the original order.

```
In [169]: ind1=np.argsort(ind)
In [170]: ind1
Out[170]: array([4, 1, 2, 0, 3], dtype=int32)
In [171]: labels[ind][ind1]
Out[171]: array([200, 201, 202, 203, 204])
In [172]:
```

I imagine you are already using an expression like this to get the top 3 values

```
In [180]: ind[:3]
Out[180]: array([3, 1, 2], dtype=int32)  # location of the top 3
In [181]: values[ind[:3]]
Out[181]: array([-5.8, -3.7, -2.1])   # the top 3
In [182]: labels[ind[:3]]
Out[182]: array([203, 201, 202])   # and their labels
```

Comment: This is by far the most elegant solution !

Answer (score 1):

The typical pattern here is decorate - sort - undecorate.

Basically, you want to sort *labels* by their value, and not values as such; so make yourself a set of value-label tuples, and sort these:

```
tuples = zip(value,labels) ## doesn't copy the elements of these two sequences, but generates a new set of references to these
sorted_tuples = sorted(tuples, key = lambda tup: tup[0])
```

Now, 6 Million entries is not *little*, but it's also not *that much* for a modern PC. Maybe you should still consider employing something that treats your data more like a raw data table than the extremely flexible, and hence references-containing (these references might be *larger* than your actual values or labels) python `list`.

```
import numpy
table = numpy.arr(vals,labels)
```

Numpy gives you a great deal of methods to work with bigger tables of data.