# Does Python/Numpy have a function that does the opposite of argsort, that fills an array with the location of that element in the sorted array?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, math

so `possort([100,50,200,5,150])`
would return

```
[2,1,4,0,3]
```

I know argsort would give:

```
[3,1,0,4,2]
```

and then I could just do

```
for i,j in enumerate(a):
    x[j]=i
```

but that seems clumsy and slow

Comment: Not sure you have your dupe-hammer pointed in the right direction @Divakar.  Looks more like he wants, for `idx = np.argsort(arr)`, `possort = idx[idx[idx]]`

Comment: @DanielF I went with the posted code, with `a` as `[3,1,0,4,2] `. Seems like thats what OP wanted.

Comment: @Divakar The result should be `[2,1,4,0,3]`, I think @DanielF is correct.

Comment: Nah, I'm not just tested it with another data set.  I know it's some trick like that though.

Comment: @kabanus From the second link : `argsort_unique(np.array([3,1,0,4,2]))` is `array([2, 1, 4, 0, 3])`.

Comment: @Divakar ah I see now, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Now I remember, it's `possort(x) = np.argsort(np.argsort(x))`

Comment: And the actual duplicate is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136244/how-can-you-get-the-order-back-after-using-argsort?rq=1)

Comment: There is [a proposal to add such a function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9880)

Comment: Thanks, I honestly tried searching for this until I got sick of having to prove I was a human for searching so many times. I suppose its tough since I cant think of a specific term to refer to what I'm looking for as opposed to what argsort gives. the argsort(argsort(x)) magic is a great trick!